# I have created a project in Ionic, but when I try to build it with the command ionic cordova build android, it returns an error which says:

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3

> (node:20056) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): CordovaError: Failed to run "javac -version", make sure that you have a JDK installed. You can get it from: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads. Your JAVA_HOME is invalid: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk
>
> (node:20056) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. [01:37:37] lint finished in 6.48 s

Answer (score 0):

Just read the error, it says it all.
Do you have Java SDK installed ?

If not, go [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) and download the good version for your operating system.

If yes, make sure that your JAVA_HOME environment variable points on the jdk location, most likely

> C:/Program Files/Java/Jdk1.8.0_161